# Customizing the UI windows for .exe ocra programs

Tags: ruby

I would like to customize the User Interface for an ocra.exe file so that the user can paste into the field and use special characters.

It would also be great to give it a NON-cmd look and feel. Where can I find information on how to do this? Can you give me some simple examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [Graphical User Interface Modules](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/GUI_Toolkit_Modules) for Ruby that you can use to create applications that look like any other Windows application with buttons, input boxes, resizable windows and all that. You can still use [Ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/) to make single file .exe's from them. The most popular are probably [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/), [FxRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/) and [WxRuby](http://wxruby.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl).